# "not those ones you have" / "not those you have"

Tags: determiners

Is a word "ones" excess or natural here? If it's excess, please, explain this rule with some examples.

I don't see "not those ones you have" on the Google Books and Ngram, only "not those you have". [[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not%20those%20ones%20you%20have%2Cnot%20those%20you%20have&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=50&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20those%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnot%20those%20you%20have%3B%2Cc0)]

> I want to try on these shoes, **not those ones** you have brought me.
>
> I want to try on these shoes, **not those** you have brought me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are idiomatically correct:

> I want **this one**.
> I want **that one**.
> I want **the one** in your hand.
> I want **the ones** in the box.

The following are not usually seen in print:

> I want **these ones**.
> I want **those ones**.

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=these+ones%2Cthose+ones%2Cthis+one%2Cthat+one&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthese%20ones%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthose%20ones%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20one%3B%2Cc0) supports this. You will hear many people utter such phrases because they are logically constructed, but many other speakers object.

So your first version is questionable.

Your second version is better, but it still sounds a little off. This would sound more literate:

> I want to try on these shoes, not the ones you have brought me.

To make a final improvement, I recommend the simple past tense:

> I want to try on these shoes, not the ones you brought me.

This is the most neutral way of saying the idea, at least to my ears. No one will think it strange.

Comment: [There's nothing wrong with **these ones/those ones** and they're perfectly idiomatic in some varieties of English!](https://www.latimes.com/socal/daily-pilot/opinion/tn-dpt-0414-casagrande-20120413-story.html)

Comment: @Jeffrey Carney, I have a pretty similar question. Could you answer, please? Which one is better to say: 1. Would you like to have this ice-cream or that? 2. Would you like to have this ice-cream or that one? 3. Would you like to have this ice-cream or that ice-cream?

Comment: @Sergey, They all seem OK. 3 is maybe too wordy. Your choice of 1 or 2 would depend on things like your physical distance to the ice creams, whether you are pointing your finger, etc.

Comment: @Jeffrey Carney, If I understand you right, the second version is the best choice, if I bring two ice-creams to a person, isn't it?